# Colocar función al acabar el juego

Tags: javascript

Presento el siguiente código en la que cada botón nos dará un resultado y los dos resultados se tienen que comparar. El caso es que la función que indica quien gana si la coloco como en el código me aparece después del resultado del primer botón y también del segundo, pero solo quiero que aparezca cuando finalice el segundo, antes no tiene mucho sentido, pero la coloque donde la coloque me sigue pasando, alguna idea?

```js
var cards = new Array(
 new Array("manzana", 1),
 new Array("manzana", 2),
 new Array("manzana", 3), 
 new Array("pera", 1),
 new Array("pera", 2),
 new Array("pera", 3),
 new Array("melon", 1),
 new Array("melon", 2),
 new Array("melon", 3)
);


var frutas1 = Array();
var frutas2 = Array();
var cuenta = 0;
var cuenta1 = 0;
var cuenta2 = 0;


 function random_card(num){
   if(cards.length >0 ){
   var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*cards.length);
   var frutas = "<br>fruta: "+cards[rand][0]+"<br><br> Valor:";
   var numero = cards[rand][1];
   document.getElementById("div"+num).innerHTML += frutas;
   document.getElementById("div"+num).innerHTML += numero;

   var repetido = 0;

   switch(num) {
    case 1:
    cuenta1++;
    cuenta = cuenta1;
    frutas1.push(numero);     

     frutas1.forEach(function(dato){
        if (dato == numero){
          repetido++;
      }
  });
 break;

    case 2:
    cuenta2++;
    cuenta = cuenta2;
    frutas2.push(numero);

     frutas2.forEach(function(dato){
         if (dato == numero){
          repetido++;
      }
  });
 break;
}    

if(repetido == 2){


  setTimeout(function(){
    var jugador = document.getElementById("player"+num+"_result");
    if (jugador.innerHTML == "0"){
      var puntua ='Se repitió el valor <br> fruta: ' + cards[rand][0] +
          ' - Valor: ' +    cards[rand][1] +'. Se extrayeron ' + cuenta +
          ' valores hasta encontrar el valor repetido.';
      jugador.innerHTML=puntua;
    } 
    winner();
  }, 100);
  }
  }  
}

function winner(){

  if(cuenta1 < cuenta2){
    alert("Jugador 1 gano!!");

  } else if(cuenta1 > cuenta2){
    alert("Jugador 2 gano!!");
  } else{
    alert("empate");
  }
 }
```

```html
<div id="start_form"></div>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="game_main">
<div id="boton"><button onclick="random_card(1);">Extraer</button>
<span id="player1"></span></div><span id="player1_result">0</span>
<div id="boton2"><button onclick="random_card(2);">Extraer</button>
<span id="player2"></span></div><span id="player2_result">0</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tengo una idea, define un `array` que va a contener booleans, entonces, al salirle cartas repetidas a algún jugador, cambiar el valor de la posición del array que le corresponde:

```
var acabados = [];
```

Supongo que num oscila entre 1 y 2, entonces simplemente hacer:

```
acabados[1]= false;
acabados[2]= false;
```

Cuando uno de los jugadores encuentre un valor repetido en su mano:

```
acabados[num]=true;
```

Y ya dentro de `winner()`:

```
function winner(){
if(acabados[1] && acabados[2]){
      if(cuenta1 < cuenta2){
        alert("Jugador 1 gano!!");

      } else if(cuenta1 > cuenta2){
        alert("Jugador 2 gano!!");
      } else{
        alert("empate");
      }
     }
 }
```

De todas formas, si puedes explicar como funciona exactamente el juego, sería bastante más fácil dar con una solución mejor y más elegante.

Comment: hola enrique mil gracias por tu respuesta. Te comento mejor de que va el "juego". Trata de que desde un botón se irán sacando numeros hasta conseguir dos iguales y se mostrará cuantos valores se han extraído hasta hasta conseguir esas dos repeticiones. Después el botón dos. Una vez los dos lo hayan hecho, se comparan cuantos han tenido que extraer uno y otro hasta las repeticiones. El que menos gana. La función winner lo consigue pero aparece dos veces, una despues del jugador uno y otra despues del dos y la intención es que solamente salga después del jugador dos. Como lo ves? Gracias!!!!

Comment: @VeroSoler en ese caso, creo que con la respuesta debería funcionar :)

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78257/discussion-on-answer-by-enrique-manzano-gil-colocar-funcion-al-acabar-el-juego).

Comment: Hola enrique! he estado probando pero no me sale, donde colocarías las variables? Lo siento por mi inexperiencia

Comment: 1. No te preocupes por la inexperiencia, todos hemos pasado por ese punto. 2. `var acabados =[];` ponla donde defines el resto de variables, al principio de tu código

Comment: PD: @VeroSoler , funciona? que a lo mejor soy yo el que se equivoca

Comment: Hola Enrique no me funciona aún y a ti? que mal me sabe

Comment: Vale, fallo mio me he equivocado ahora al escribirlo xD

Comment: Ya está corregida la respuesta, ahora sí debería funcionar :P

Comment: ya está! gracias enrique por todo!!

Comment: De nada, siempre para intentar ayudar :)

Answer (score 1):

Creo que para que tu juego tenga un mayor sentido hay que limitar los turnos de cada jugador, es decir, que cuando un jugador presione el botón el mismo sistema obligue al segundo jugador a presionarlo, así se mantendrán los turnos y se podrá informar cual fue el ganador y cual fue el perdedor:

```js
var cards = new Array(
 new Array("manzana", 1),
 new Array("manzana", 2),
 new Array("manzana", 3), 
 new Array("pera", 1),
 new Array("pera", 2),
 new Array("pera", 3),
 new Array("melon", 1),
 new Array("melon", 2),
 new Array("melon", 3)
);

var frutas1 = Array();
var frutas2 = Array();
var cuenta = 0;
var cuenta1 = 0;
var cuenta2 = 0;

var boton1 = document.getElementById("boton");
var boton2 = document.getElementById("boton2");


function random_card(num){
   if(cards.length >0 ){
   var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*cards.length);
   var frutas = "<br>fruta: "+cards[rand][0]+"<br><br> Valor:";
   var numero = cards[rand][1];
   document.getElementById("player"+num).innerHTML += frutas;
   document.getElementById("player"+num).innerHTML += numero;

   var repetido = 0;

   switch(num) {
    case 1:
    frutas1.push(numero);     

     frutas1.forEach(function(dato){
        if (dato == numero){
          repetido++;
          cuenta1++;
          cuenta = cuenta1;
      }
     });
     
     boton1.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
     boton2.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].removeAttribute('disabled');
 break;

    case 2:
    frutas2.push(numero);

     frutas2.forEach(function(dato){
         if (dato == numero){
          repetido++;
          cuenta2++;
          cuenta = cuenta2;
      }
    });
    
    boton2.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
     boton1.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].removeAttribute('disabled');
 break;
}    

if(repetido == 2){


  setTimeout(function(){
    var jugador = document.getElementById("player"+num+"_result");
    if (jugador.innerHTML == "0"){
      var puntua ='Se repitió el valor <br> fruta: ' + cards[rand][0] +
          ' - Valor: ' +    cards[rand][1] +'. Se extrayeron ' + cuenta +
          ' valores hasta encontrar el valor repetido.';
      jugador.innerHTML=puntua;
    } 
    winner();
  }, 100);
  }
  }  
}

function winner(){
  if(cuenta1 > cuenta2){
    alert("Jugador 1 gano!!");

  } else if(cuenta1 < cuenta2){
    alert("Jugador 2 gano!!");
  } else{
    alert("empate");
  }
  
  boton1.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  boton2.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
 }
```

```html
<div id="start_form"></div>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="game_main">
<div id="boton"><button onclick="random_card(1);">Extraer</button>
<span id="player1"></span></div><span id="player1_result">0</span>
<div id="boton2"><button onclick="random_card(2);">Extraer</button>
<span id="player2"></span></div><span id="player2_result">0</span>
```

Comment: Hola @Bender ! precisamente lo que busco es lo contrario, que acabe el primero, luego el segundo y se comparen el numero de extracciones. La función winner lo consigue pero aparece despues del primer jugador y también del segundo cuando solo deberia salir despues del segundo, ahí es cuando ya no se donde colocar la funcion winner para que salga. Gracias!